# install npm for Magento 2 on a system the runs Plesk Onyx without deleteing Plesk

Tags: magento2, grunt, linux, npm

When i try to **install npm** per **apt-get** on my Linux machine with Plesk onyx it always want to remove my plesk packages. i still wanna use plesk on my server since its my developer environment. but i need npm for magento 2 because i need to install grunt with it.

any idea how i can install npm on the server without loosing plesk ? i know plesk supports nodejs in the web interface but i need to call npm on the cli. ...realy need yall help. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed Node.js native support in Plesk Onyx, you can use npm in CLI as

/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm

or

/opt/plesk/node/6/bin/npm

Also, I would suggest you read this thread on Plesk forum https://talk.plesk.com/threads/magento-2-situation.339465/